# How to find length of side of smaller scalene triangle inside larger scalene triangle

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

I'm dealing with a real-world problem that can be abstracted into triangles. The knowns are:

- length of $AB$
- length of $CB$
- length of $AC$
- length of $EF$
- $EF$ and $AC$ are parallel

In other words, the larger triangle's sides, along with one side of the smaller triangle in the interior

What I want to know:

- length of $EB$, or
- length of $FB$, or
- length of any line that originates on the $EF$ line and terminates at $B$

[image]
What math can I look up or what else do I need to know in order to get my want-to-knows?
Thanks!

Comment: You have insufficient data (you can see that by trying to draw a different $EF$ with the same length). To finish you need one more number - one of the lengths or one of the angles at $E$ or $F$.

Comment: Most important thing:  from the drawing it appears that $\overline {EF}$ is parallel to $\overline {AC}$ but that's not stated anywhere.  If that is true, then look up Similarity of Triangles.  If it's false, then you need a lot more information about the angles.

Comment: EF is indeed parallel to AC so I will look up the Similarity of Triangles and edit my question! @lulu

Comment: Thank you @EthanBolker for your suggestion as well.

Comment: If corresponding angles of two triangles are the same, then the triangles are similar. Since EF is parallel to AC and both triangles share an apex, then they are similar. Since the are similar, the ratio of AB to EB is the same as the ratio of AC to EF. Something similar applies to the other legs.